# Static Assets URL as absolute path or relative path in API Response

Tags: json, api, assets, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a Spring boot API service ,    other websites and mobile apps call this API for data and images.
Images are stored in file system and file path in database.
I am looking for best practice to return  image URLs in API response.

**Sample DB Record**

```
 +-----+-------+-----------------+
| Id  | Name  | profile_img_url |
+-----+-------+-----------------+
|  1  | John  | /image/john.jpg |
|  2  | Jane  | /image/jane.jpg |
|  3  | Doe   | /image/doe.jpg  |
+-----+-------+-----------------+
```

For example I have a member API.

```
https://example.com/get/member/id
```

This API will return JSON , which has member image URL

Should I return profile_img_url as absolute URL or relative URL

Here are my thoughts

**Response with Relative URL**

```
{
"name" : "John",
"profile_img_url": "/image/john.jpg",
}
```

- In API code , No need to worry about base URL(domain name), the calling website or mobile
  app need to take care of the base URL.
- In API  I just read and send the profile img url and need not spend time in concatenating  domain name and file name
  to make  absolute URL, so response should be fast.

**Response with Absolute URL**

```
{
"name" : "John",
"profile_img_url": "https://example.com/image/john.jpg",
}
```

- In my API , I need to find the host name and concatenate the file
  path for every request leading to unnecessary load on API server.
- If I am returning a list of member, I need to fetch from DB and loop
  through the list and make absolute URL.  this can make the API
  response slower.
- Also I need to ensure, my API server behind proxy or load balance,
  can detect the domain/ host name and use it for concatenating
- Calling website or mobile app, need not worry about base URL/domain
  name
- I dont have to educate the mobile team or client app development team
  on how to get the profile image
- In future, if i  decide to server my images from different domain or
  sub domain,  I dont have to inform  other teams

If it is a simple website (front end+back end together) , I think relative URL would be sufficient for a website unless you are running high traffic website  which needs very high performance optimization.

In my case I run only back end API.  Front End will be  other applications / mobile apps  of our company or our partners

you can also read [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/never-use-an-absolute-path-for-your-apis-again-9ee9199563be/) page, though it is not directly related to my question, but it talks about issue related to URLs in  decoupled system

so what is the best practice , absolute or relative URL  in a API response.